# Merge signal in flat sequance

Tags: labview

I have three inputs in merge signals in different time, the out put of merge signals appeared to wait for all signals and outputted them. what I want is to have an output for every signal (on current output) as soon as it inputted.

For example: if I write (1) in initial value. 5,5,5 in all three numeric. with 3 sec time delay, I will have 6,7,and 16 in target 1, target 2, and target 3. And over all 16 on current output. I don't want that to appear at once on current output. I want to have as it appears in target with same time layout. 
please see attached photo.

can anyone help me with that. 
thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All nodes in LabVIEW fire when all their inputs arrive. This language uses synchronous data flow, not asynchronous (which is the behavior you were describing).

The output of Merge Signals is a single data structure that contains all the input signals — merged, like the name says. :-)

To get the behavior you want, you need some sort of asynchronous communication. In older versions of LabVIEW, I would tell you to create a queue refnum and go look at examples of a producer/consumer pattern.

But in LabVIEW 2016 and later, right click on each of the tunnels coming out of your flat sequence and chose “Create>>Channel Writer...”. In the dialog that appears, choose the Messenger channel. Wire all the outputs of the new nodes together. This creates an asynchronous wire, which draws very differently from your regular wires. On the wire, right click and choose “Create>>Channel Reader...”. Put the reader node inside a For Loop and wire a 3 to the N terminal. Now you have the behavior that as each block finishes, it will send its data to the loop.

Move the Write nodes inside the Flat Sequence if you want to guarantee the enqueue order. If you wait and do the Writes outside, you’ll sometimes get out-of-order data (I.e. when the data generation nodes happen to run quickly).

Side note: I (and most LabVIEW architects) would strongly recommend you avoid using sequence structures as much as possible. They’re a bad habit to get into — lots of writings online about their disadvantages.